# Remove blank option but do not set an initial option to the first value

Tags: html, angularjs, ng-options

I want to get rid of an empty option generated in my select.

```
<option value="?" selected="selected"></option>
```

What I also want to do is NOT set the first element automatically. Basically once select is untouched the value should be empty but once user clicks on the select they cannot see that empty option in there. If unselected without selecting an option, select should remain empty.

So I don't want to end up with this
http://jsfiddle.net/MTfRD/6518/

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {

   $scope.typeOptions = [
      { name: 'Feature', value: 'feature' }, 
      { name: 'Bug', value: 'bug' }, 
      { name: 'Enhancement', value: 'enhancement' }
   ];

   $scope.form = {type : $scope.typeOptions[0].value};
}
```

```html
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <select ng-model='form.type' required 
        ng-options='option.value as option.name for option in typeOptions'>
    </select>
</div>
```

I have looked at tens of posts that suggest this answer but it doesn't solve my problem.

This is the desired behaviour
[image: This is the desired behaviour]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply do a hack like this,

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <select ng-model='form.type' required ng-options='option.value as option.name for option in typeOptions'>
          <option value="" style="display: none"></option>
    </select>
</div>
```

**DEMO**

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);


function MyCtrl($scope) {
    
    $scope.typeOptions = [
    { name: 'Feature', value: 'feature' }, 
    { name: 'Bug', value: 'bug' }, 
    { name: 'Enhancement', value: 'enhancement' }
    ];
 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <select ng-model='form.type' required ng-options='option.value as option.name for option in typeOptions'>
          <option value="" style="display: none"></option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: For me it's only added extra 'hidden' empty option. value="?" empty option is still there. At the moment I have <option value="" style="display: none" class=""></option> as well as <option value="?" selected="selected"></option>

Comment: remove the option value selected from the dropdown as mentioned in the demo

Comment: Isn't that what I've done? Added <option value="" style="display: none"></option> with empty value and got rid of that extra line in the controller

Comment: Right! Didn't notice I still had $scope.form = {type: ''} in my controller

Comment: yeah as you told you need to remove that

Answer (score 0):

Try this.. its like placeholder

```
 <option selected disabled>Choose here</option>
```